# cant build a sequential model of lstm cells

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, edward

I had used a code for bayesian lstm by using edward2 library from a paper Bayesian Layers: A Module for Neural Network Uncertainty
:

```
lstm=ed.layers.LSTMCellReparameterization(8)
output_layer=tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)
def loss_fn(x,lable,datasetsize):
    state = lstm.get_initial_state(x)
    nll = 0.
    for t in range(x.shape[0]):
        net, state = lstm(x, state)
        logits = output_layer(net)
        nll += tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                              lable, logits=logits))
    k1 = sum(lstm.losses) / datasetsize
    loss=nll+k1
    returnloss
loss1=loss_fn(b1,Y,2000)
```

I want to use this code to train a neural network. Could someone help me?

Comment: What is your question, exaclty? Please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: What is the exact error in your code?
Kindly provide the complete source code of your sequential model of lstm cells?